# std::ostringstream operator overload search order?

Tags: c++, stl, overload-resolution

I have the following class:

```
namespace {
class MimeLogger : public std::ostringstream
{
public:
    MimeLogger()
    {}

    ~MimeLogger()
    {
        LOGEVENT( logModuleWSE, logEventDebug, logMsgWSETrace1, str() );
    }
};
}
```

When I do this:

```
MimeLogger() << "Hello " << "World";
```

The first `"Hello "` string is treated as a `void*`. If I debug the code, `"Hello "` is passed into `std::basic_ostream::operator<< (void const*)` and prints as a pointer value, not a string. The second string, `"World"` is properly passed into the global overloaded << operator that takes a `char const*`.

I expect both usages of the << operator to resolve to the same overload, but this does not happen. Can someone explain, and maybe propose a fix?

Thanks in advance.

### Update

I neglected to mention that I'm stuck with C++03, but I'm glad that some people covered both the C++03 and C++11 cases.

Comment: I've heard that you shouldn't subclass Standard Library classes but maybe that was just for container objects... I'm new at C++

Comment: The streams classes were designed to be subclassed off of.  That said, it's usually the base streams classes (`std::istream` and `std::ostream`) that get subclassed, rather than `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: How about containment of ostringstream and writing an operator<< overload ?

Comment: Are you defining your own overloaded operators?  If so, can you post them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++03: For the expression `MimeLogger() << "Hello "`, the template function

```
template <typename charT, class traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& std::operator<< (
    std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os,
    const char* cstr);
```

is not considered during overload resolution because the temporary `MimeLogger()` may not be bound to a non-const reference.  The member function overloads do not have this problem because the rules for the implicit parameter do allow binding to a temporary.

If you can use a compiler with support for C++11 rvalue-references, this should work as you intended, because the C++11 library provides an additional overload

```
template <typename charT, class traits, typename T>
std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& std::operator<< (
    std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os,
    const T& x ); // { os << x; return os; }
```

which allows temporary streams to be used left of `<<` as though they were not temporary.

(I did try a test program with g++ and got different results without and with -std=c++0x.)

If you cannot use a C++11 friendly compiler, adding this to the public section of `class MimeLogger` is a workaround that will do what you want with C++03:

```
template<typename T>
MimeLogger& operator<<(const T& x)
{
    static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(*this) << x;
    return *this;
}

using std::ostringstream::operator<<;
```

The using-declaration makes sure the member overloads from the standard library are also visible from `MimeLogger`.  In particular, without it manipulators like `std::endl` don't work with the template operator, since `std::endl` is itself a function template, and that's too much template type deduction to expect from C++.  But things are fine as long as we're sure not to hide the `ostream` member that makes the function manipulators work (27.7.3.6.3):

```
namespace std {
    template <typename charT, class traits>
    class basic_ostream : /*...*/ {
    public:
        basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(
            basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&));
    };
}
```

Comment: Will your overloaded operator handle `std::endl`? If not, how would I make that work for C++03?

Answer (score 0):

How about using containment of `std::ostringstream`    ?

```
class MimeLogger
{
private:
    std::ostringstream oss_m;

public:
    MimeLogger()
    {
    }

    ~MimeLogger()
    {
        std::cout << __FILE__ << "(" << __LINE__ << "):" << oss_m.str() << "\n";
    }

    template<typename Type>
    MimeLogger& operator<<(const Type& t)
    {
        oss_m << t;
        return *this;
    }
};


void LogDemo()
{       
   MimeLogger logger;
   logger << "Hello " << "World!!\n";
   MimeLogger() << "Hello " << "StackOverflow!!\n";
}
```

Comment: That function `LogDemo` will actually work "as expected" even with the OP original version of class `MimeLogger`.

Comment: OP says he gets the address printed instead of "Hello".

Comment: Yes, but there's a subtle difference between `MimeLogger() << "Hello ";` and `MimeLogger logger; logger << "Hello ";`.

Comment: I use inheritance so I don't have to redundantly implement the operators again. The std lib will do this for me. Plus, I'm not sure how your overloaded operator would handle `std::endl`. It's a function technically I think. Also I can't create an actual named temporary in my case, I absolutely have to stick with unnamed temporary and fit it all on one line for this to work.